# How to tar a file with Commons Compress that is too large and causes out of memory crash?

Tags: java, tar, apache-commons

In the code below, if I give (Apache) Commons Compress a single file a few gigabytes in size it will crash because it uses up all of my memory.

Can I make it read and then write small pieces of the file at a time? I've been researching chunking, but I'm not sure how to do that so that i can put the file back together after the pieces have been written into a .tar format.

What's the best way to deal with supporting files of any size here?

```
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("output.tar");
BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
GzipCompressorOutputStream gzipOutputStream = new GzipCompressorOutputStream(bufferedOutputStream);
TarArchiveOutputStream tarArchiveOutputStream = new TarArchiveOutputStream(gzipOutputStream)) {

tarArchiveOutputStream.setBigNumberMode(TarArchiveOutputStream.BIGNUMBER_POSIX);
tarArchiveOutputStream.setLongFileMode(TarArchiveOutputStream.LONGFILE_GNU);

File currentFile = new File("Huge_MultiGB_File.txt");
String relativeFilePath = currentFile.getPath();
TarArchiveEntry tarEntry = new TarArchiveEntry(currentFile, relativeFilePath);
tarEntry.setSize(currentFile.length());
tarArchiveOutputStream.putArchiveEntry(tarEntry);
tarArchiveOutputStream.write(IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream(currentFile)));
tarArchiveOutputStream.closeArchiveEntry();
```

Comment: what is tarArchiveOutputStream ?

Comment: I've added that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write small portion of file and write that to output in loop instead of reading whole file to memory first with `IOUtils`

It is done more or less like this:

```
FileInputStream source=new FileInputStream(....somefile);
tarArchiveOutputStream; prepared to w writing

byte[] buff = new byte[1024*10]; //10kb buff
int numBytesRead = -1; //number of bytes read


while(( numBytesRead = source.read(buff)) > 0 ) {
    // while source has bytes, read from source and write
    // the same number of bytes to the tar outputstream
    tarArchiveOutputStream.write(buff, 0, numBytesRead);
   }
}
```

Comment: Ok, ill try and find some examples of that. If you have any example code of how to do that feel free to share. I'm new to java, and taring files.

Comment: It is a very common scenario.

Comment: I just don't know how to do that with Apache. The code takes an input file as an argument and a destination as an argument. How do i tell it to loop through and write small pieces of the file at at time?